# create sectionList with a title that compares the today's date and the date from the array?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

So I have an array with a data of

```
var today = "2020-08-31"
var array = [
{
  name: "Joshua", 
  id: 1, 
  date: "2020-08-31"
}, 
{
  name: "Michael", 
  id: 2, 
  date: "2020-09-1"
}]
```

I want to create a **sectionList** that the *sectionHeader title* will be depending on the date today and will compare it to the date value from the array. so for example the date from the array is "2020-08-31" and today's date is same as "2020-08-31" the title should be "Today" and tomorrow is "2020-09-01" and the  date from the array is still "2020-08-31" the title should be "Yesterday" is it possible?? please help me. im stuck with this. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the parse function from the JS Date library to parse the date hence convert it into long and then return the string (yesterday, today, tomorrow).

Add the displayDate into you array in order to loop through and display the field's value.

```js
const today = "2020-08-31"
let array = [{
    name: "Joshua",
    id: 1,
    date: "2020-08-31"
  },
  {
    name: "Michael",
    id: 2,
    date: "2020-09-1"
  }
]

array = array.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  displayDate: (() => {
    if (Date.parse(today) < Date.parse(x.date)) {
      return 'yesterday';
    } else if (Date.parse(today) > Date.parse(x.date)) {
      return 'tomorrow';
    }
    return 'today';
  })()
}));

console.log(array)
```